# Multi dimensional JSON Array SQL Query

Tags: postgresql, query, json, array

I'm struggling to write an appropriate query for my data ->

```
   "schools":[
      {
         "org_symbol":"School 1",
         "criteria":[
            [
               {
                  "value":"private",
                  "type":"school type"
               },
               {
                  "value":"usa",
                  "type":"country"
               },
               {
                  "value":"english",
                  "type":"language"
               },
               {
                  "value":"1-6",
                  "type":"grades"
               },
               {
                  "value":"Silver",
                  "type":"level"
               }
            ]
         ]
      },
      {
         "org_symbol":"School 2",
         "criteria":[
            [
               {
                  "value":"private",
                  "type":"school type"
               },
               {
                  "value":"usa",
                  "type":"country"
               },
               {
                  "value":"english",
                  "type":"language"
               },
               {
                  "value":"1-6",
                  "type":"grades"
               },
               {
                  "value":"gold",
                  "type":"level"
               }
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have this

```
SELECT distinct on(id) * FROM tribes, json_array_elements(meta::json -> 'attributes') as elem 
WHERE 
( 
    (elem ->> 'type' = 'school type' and elem ->> 'value' = 'private') 
    and (elem ->> 'type' = 'country' and elem ->> 'value' = 'usa') 
    and (elem ->> 'type' = 'language' and elem ->> 'value' = 'english')
    and (elem ->> 'type' = 'grades' and elem ->> 'value' = '1-6')
    and (elem ->> 'type' = 'level' and elem ->> 'value' = 'gold')
  ) ;
```

but it doesn't return anything, I know i'm indexing correctly (full json not included) but I can't seem to get the multi query to work. I need to be able to check where value and type match each set of criteria

I think i'm close but really not sure, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't see any key name `attributes` in your sample data. So obviously `-> 'attributes'` returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is at least one school entry in the `schools` array that contains all those key/value pairs, you can use the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from tribes
where meta -> 'schools' @> '[{"criteria": [[ {"value": "usa", "type": "country"}, 
                                             {"value": "private", "type": "school type"},
                                             {"value": "english", "type": "language"},
                                             {"value": "1-6", "type": "grades"},
                                             {"value": "gold", "type": "level"}
                                          ]]
                            }]';
```

This assumes that `meta` is a `jsonb` column (which it really should be). If it's not you'll have to cast it: `meta::jsonb`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d9fd97f1d199d59e87b8757f7d9589fe)